# Hibernate criteria query error: java.util.List cannot be converted to org.hibernate.mapping.List

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to both Java and Hibernate. I am following the most rudimentary examples for doing a query with criteria that I find in the Hibernate documentation and a number of tutorials. With this code:

```
public void simpleQuery()
{
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Resource.class);

    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("Name","NTO"));

    List result = criteria.list();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:(30, 44) java: incompatible types: java.util.List cannot be converted to org.hibernate.mapping.List
```

Resource is a plain Hibernate entity. I generated it with hbm2java and have used it successfully in a unit test to insert into the corresponding teable.

I have tried

```
List<Object> result = criteria.list();
```

but that also results in a cast exception.

I am working in IntelliJ 14.1.3 with JDK 1.8.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Change  `org.hibernate.mapping.List` to `java.util.List` in your `Resource` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect imports at the top of the class. Replace

```
import org.hibernate.mapping.List;
```

by

```
import java.util.List
```

And don't use raw types. Use `List<Resource>` and not `List`, since your query is supposed to return a list of instances of Resource.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I got thrown by the fact that none of the examples appear to work that way and that the list() method seemed to want to return org.hibernate.maping.list. Many thanks!